# Cannot boot from SD card/flash drive on Macbook Pro 13" - boot fails after purple screen

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, macbook

It's my first time using Ubuntu and I have run into some problems.

I have a 16GB USB Flash drive and 16GB SDHC Card. I would prefer to use the SD card but either will do just fine if it helps with the solution.

I Have a 13" Macbook Pro with no hard drive deeming the machine useless without an OS.

I thought I could substitute the hard drive for a 16GB SD card with an Ubuntu ISO on it.

I would like to plug in my SD card into my Macbook Pro, boot the Ubuntu ISO and do simple things such as use the browser for internet.

**The Problem:**
Whenever I boot my Macbook pro with the SD card that has the Ubuntu ISO, it loads at the purple logo screen and does not function. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How do you have the Ubuntu ISO configured? It will not just load if you put it on the card (it isn't like a dmg file). You need to configure it to load.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a few things:

- Check to make sure you don't have any 32-bit versus 64-bit problems (Use 32-bit if you are unsure
- Use a version of ubuntu that is current with the machine. I am on a MacBook Pro from 2011 and I started it with 12.10. Look for compatibility lists online for your version of Ubuntu
- Check the USB drive in another computer to make sure it works, could be having formatting issues. Or try a different USB stick
- Maybe give whatever you try extra time, my old computer took 15 minutes to boot into Ubuntu back in the day.

Good luck, hope this helps!!